# How to redirect file output to a different directory?

Tags: directory, symlink, directory-structure

I have a program that regularly outputs files to a directory, let's say `/a/b`. I am utterly unable to change where these files are outputted. But for me to use them, I must first move them to, let's say, `/c/d`, an **already existing** directory. I'm growing tired of regularly moving over the file contents, so is there some way to redirect everything written in that directory to another? I've already tried `ln -s` but with my limited knowledge of the linking command I couldn't accomplish anything. Changing any code of the program is not possible. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

short of being able to delete /a/b directory, your `ln -s` command will not give you anything.

but if you can find a few seconds that nothing is writing to this `/a/b` directory, you can do this :

```
cd /a
rm -r b   # make sure you have a backup of the contents of this directory 
ln -s /c/d b
```

now any application who will write into `/a/b`, will be directed to write these files into `/c/d`, provided they have write rights.

Comment: Okay, that seems like it would work, but one more question - `/c/d` is in a different partition. I need the data to write to this partition (in order to save space on the other), does `ln -s` perform this function?

Comment: the `-s` in the command means symbolic link and symbolic links do not have to be in the same partition. That limitation is for the hard links which has to be in the same filesystem

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
while :; do cp /a/b/* /c/d/; sleep 60; done
```

It copies the entire content of /a/b/ to /c/d/ every 60 seconds.

It does have a drawback: If the files are big (more than a few GB?) then copying might take a while. If this is a problem, comment and I'll implement something optimised for big files (with [tail -f](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail)) which will also redirect the content in real time